# PowerShell [Math]::Round sometimes not rounding?

Tags: powershell, rounding

I'm having struggle trying to figure out why some times the substraction of two rounded values gives me a non-rounded value. Is like if 2.2 - 1.1 = 1.10000001.

I have this block of a script in PowerShell:

```
foreach($disk in $disks) 
{
    $size = $disk.Size
    $freespace = $disk.FreeSpace
    $percentFree = [Math]::Round(($freespace / $size) * 100)
    $sizeGB = [Math]::Round($size / 1073741824, 2)
    $freeSpaceGB = [Math]::Round($freespace / 1073741824, 2)
    $usedSpaceGB = $sizeGB - $freeSpaceGB

    #view the variable values in every iteration
    Write-Debug "`$size = $size"
    Write-Debug "`$freespace = $freespace"
    Write-Debug "`$percentFree = $percentFree%"
    Write-Debug "`$sizeGB = $sizeGB"
    Write-Debug "`$freeSpaceGB = $freeSpaceGB"
    Write-Debug "`$usedSpaceGB = $usedSpaceGB"
}
```

The troubling part is:

```
$usedSpaceGB = $sizeGB - $freeSpaceGB
```

The [Math]::Round() method seems to work as intended, because I can see the rounded values stored in $sizeGB and $freeSpaceGB variables. Here are some debug output examples:

[image: debug output 1]
 [image: debug output 2]

1. I don't understand why in some cases the subtraction of two previously rounded values results in a non-rounded value as you can see in example images.
2. This behavior happens in the same exact positions of the loop, lets say in the 7, 10 and 18 iteration.

I export this data to an HTML file so the table looks odd with this values not rounded:

[image]

Right now I "fixed" this by Rounding also the subtraction result but I'm wondering why is this happening. I hope someone can help me to understand what is going on.

Comment: I assume `$disks` is a collection of [`Win32_LogicalDisk`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa394173.aspx) instances? If so, `FreeSpace` and `Size` are integer types (both `UInt64`), but by passing them to [`Math.Round`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.math.round.aspx) you are getting a `Double` back, which is then subject to the usual issue of [floating-point numbers not being able to exactly represent some numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089018/why-cant-decimal-numbers-be-represented-exactly-in-binary). I would round only the final output, not intermediate values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alright, let's try this as an answer...

I am assuming `$disks` is a collection of [`Win32_LogicalDisk`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa394173.aspx) instances, in which case the `FreeSpace` and `Size` properties are integer types (specifically, `UInt64`).  If `$disks` contains some other type(s), those two properties are likely integers of some kind since we're dealing with byte counts.

This is somewhat extraneous to the question, but in this line...

```
$percentFree = [Math]::Round(($freespace / $size) * 100)
```

...`$percentFree` will contain a `Double` even though you're calling [the `Math.Round` overload that rounds to the nearest integer](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.math.round#System_Math_Round_System_Double_) because that's the return type of that method.  You can inspect this by evaluating...

```
$percentFree.GetType()
```

If you want/expect `$percentFree` to contain an integer type then you need to cast it to one, like this...

```
$percentFree = [UInt64] [Math]::Round(($freespace / $size) * 100)
```

The above also applies when you are using `Math.Round` to round to the nearest hundredth...

```
$sizeGB = [Math]::Round($size / 1073741824, 2)
$freeSpaceGB = [Math]::Round($freespace / 1073741824, 2)
```

...because, of course, that method overload has to return a floating-point type since, by definition, an integer type could not store fractions of a value.  Thus, `$sizeGB` and `$freeSpaceGB` contain floating-point values (specifically `Double`) so when this line...

```
$usedSpaceGB = $sizeGB - $freeSpaceGB
```

...is executed `$usedSpaceGB` will also contain a `Double`, in which case all bets are off as far as it [being able to exactly represent the resulting value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089018/why-cant-decimal-numbers-be-represented-exactly-in-binary).

Hopefully that explains why this is happening.  As far as how to improve your code, first I would recommend not doing any rounding on intermediate values...

```
$sizeGB = $size / 1073741824
$freeSpaceGB = $freespace / 1073741824
$usedSpaceGB = [Math]::Round($sizeGB - $freeSpaceGB, 2)
```

...which can be written more clearly and concisely as...

```
$sizeGB = $size / 1GB
$freeSpaceGB = $freespace / 1GB
$usedSpaceGB = [Math]::Round($sizeGB - $freeSpaceGB, 2)
```

This won't eliminate floating-point approximations like you're seeing, but `$usedSpaceGB` will be closer to the actual value since you're not computing based on the already-rounded (which discards some information) values of `$sizeGB` and `$freeSpaceGB`.

In the previous snippets, `$usedSpaceGB` is still a `Double` so it's still possible it computes to some value that can't be represented exactly.  Since this value is being formatted for display or otherwise must be serialized to a `string` (as HTML) I would just forget about `Math.Round` and let [`string` formatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings) handle the rounding for you like this...

```
$usedSpaceGBText = (($size - $freeSpace) / 1GB).ToString('N2')
```

...or this...

```
$usedSpaceGBText = '{0:N2}' -f (($size - $freeSpace) / 1GB)
```

Comment: Well change Math.Round for .ToString('N2') solved the problem. Thanks.

Comment: Very weird that even in pwsh `7.4.0` this rounding issue still occurs. The `round()` function should have been fixed to be smart enough to handle bitsize and casts by itself.