# Why Math operator is not rounding with correct values.?

Tags: powershell

When I am trying to round the values the results are different. Please observe the below Output. It rounds up for Odd numbers only. What's wrong I am doing.

```
PS C:\> [math]::Round(1.5)
2

PS C:\> [math]::Round(2.5)
2

PS C:\> [math]::Round(3.5)
4

PS C:\> [math]::Round(4.5)
4

PS C:\> [math]::Round(5.5)
6

PS C:\> [math]::Round(6.5)
6
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PowerShell \[Math\]::Round sometimes not rounding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46286675/powershell-mathround-sometimes-not-rounding)

Comment: @LotPings - It looks more like math is using bankers rounding

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48864295/powershell-int-variable-with-decimal-number/48864546#48864546) explanation for more clarity!

Comment: Alternatively you can use the string format `N0` as in `"{0,N0}" -f 2.5` or `(2.5).ToString('N0')`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`[math]` uses bankers rounding

From the comment section in [Rounding numbers](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2015/01/30/rounding-numberspowershell-style/)

> ...which means numbers are rounded to the nearest even number. This
>   doesn’t follow the rules I learned with math rounding where something
>   ending in 5 is always rounded  up to the next higher level number. To
>   get the Round function to behave the way most of us learned math
>   rules, you use the additional AwayFromZero switch *(Dan Sheehan)*.

If you always want to round up, you can use [AwayFromZero](https://www.madwithpowershell.com/2013/10/math-in-powershell.html)

```
[math]::Round(2.5, 0, [System.MidpointRounding]::AwayFromZero)
```

Comment: I was about to posting the same link, might be easier/shorter to add `.001`

Comment: Shorter indeed but impov the intent is more explicit using AwayFromZero and it at least gives you something to search on ;) *(it was new to me)*